# Boolean attribute based out attributes in different classes

Tags: java, class, attributes

I am making a boolean attribute that bases its outcome on the values provided by two other attributes, one within the same class, but another within a different class. Is this possible as long as I use public classes?

Comment: As long as you can see the class and the variable, then yes of course this is possible. The class doesn't necessarily have to be public, it would depend on its package and if your other class extends it. Please read up on Java access modifiers.

Comment: are we talking about public classes and static fields?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as you provide proper visibility to the members (booleans, in your case) in the other class - you're good. This can be done by defining those members as public, but better yet - by providing a public getter that returns the value of those members.